# Replace 0 with next non zero element in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array :

```
Array
(
[0] =>Array(
    [total_users]=>101
)
[1] =>Array(
    [total_users]=>100
)
[2] =>Array(
    [total_users]=>0
)
[3] =>Array(
    [total_users]=>0
)
[4] =>Array(
    [total_users]=>88
)
[5] =>Array(
    [total_users]=>78
)
[6] =>Array(
    [total_users]=>0
)
[7] =>Array(
    [total_users]=>56
)

)
```

Now what I need is I need to replace the zero values with the next non zero value in a foreach loop. I mean I need to get 88 on index 2 and 3 as it is the next non zero value. Also in in dex 6 I need to have 56. How can I do this  ?

Comment: try something, then we can try to make it work, but before asking please always try something yourself.

Comment: Yesh I have tried something. Adding that also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop trough the array backwards:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        array('total_users' => 101),
        array('total_users' => 100),
        array('total_users' =>   0),
        array('total_users' =>   0),
        array('total_users' =>  88),
        array('total_users' =>  78),
        array('total_users' =>   0),
        array('total_users' =>  56)
    );

    for ($i = count($array) - 2; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        if ($array[$i]['total_users'] == 0) {
            $array[$i]['total_users'] = $array[$i + 1]['total_users'];
        }
    }

    print_r($array);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array( [total_users] => 101 )
    [1] => Array( [total_users] => 100 )
    [2] => Array( [total_users] =>  88 )
    [3] => Array( [total_users] =>  88 )
    [4] => Array( [total_users] =>  88 )
    [5] => Array( [total_users] =>  78 )
    [6] => Array( [total_users] =>  56 )
    [7] => Array( [total_users] =>  56 )
)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/oOnPu4es)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   $arr_length = sizeof($your_array);  
$pre_val = 0;     
for($i=arr_length-1; $i>=0; $i--)
{
    if($your_array[$i]['total_users']==0)
    {
        $your_array[$i]['total_users'] = $pre_val;
    }
    else
    {
        $pre_val = $your_array[$i]['total_users'];
    }   

}   

print_r($your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might loop through the array backwards.

Keep in a variable last non-zero value, and when you encounter zero, replace it with this value in the array.